# 404 Handling (If this page returns 404, use this page) - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitch

I tried to search for this topic but I didn't see one that I was looking for. For instance I have this URL:

```
http://www.twitchalerts.com/tip/' + user.username +'/
```

---

```
                        <ul id="grnstaff">
                        <li ng-repeat="user in profile | orderBy:orderByValue:reverse" ng-click="changeSrc('cbox','http://www.twitch.tv/' + user.username +'/chat');changeSrc('tbox','http://www.twitch.tv/' + user.username +'/embed');changeSrc('tip','http://www.twitchalerts.com/' + user.username +'/');" ng-style="{ 'background-color' : (user.streaming) ? '#ccffcc' : '#EAEAEA' }">
                            <img ng-src="{{user.logo}}" err-src="images/twitch-default.jpg" class="pic"/>
                            <span class="name">{{user.name}}</span>
                            <span class="status"><i class="{{user.status}}"></i></span>
                            <span class="title">{{user.streamTitle}} <i class="{{user.tv}}"></i> {{user.viewers}}</span>
                        </li> 
                    </ul>
```

The above is the part that is laying out the twitch boxes, there's 3 iframes, 1 for chat, 1 for the stream, and 1 for a streamalerts tip window where viewers can tip the streamer without leaving the page.

What I want the 'tip' iframe to do: I want to, if one of the users on my list does NOT have a tip page, then to go to a local page saying that the streamer does not have a tip page set up (If streamer twitchalerts page returns 404, use no_tips.php instead)

Is there a way to do this? I couldn't find a way to do what I'm wanting to do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add code/attempt you have done for this?

Comment: Added the snippet of the piece that I am trying to do this in.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Not extremely clear what you are trying to do

Comment: You probably want to use router `resolve` to check user and redirect from that

Comment: I added what the above piece is doing.  Hope it explains it clearer. Apologies again.

Comment: do you have access to the server's `.htaccess` file? you can implement a simple 404 redirect in there.

Comment: I don't unfortunately

Comment: Just add an http response error interceptor to your `changeSrc` function and use the `ng-if` directive show the local page. If you want more details, we need to see the code for the `changeSrc` function.